# How to make a two column table entry closer to the center of the table?

Tags: tables, revtex

So the latex code below creates a two-column table that places entries to the leftmost and the right most. I just want to retain the overall layout but places the column entries nearer to the center of the table. How do I do it?

(Revtex4-1)

```
\documentclass[reprint, superscriptaddress, showpacs, preprintnumbers, amsmath, amssymb, aps, prb]{revtex4-1}
\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\begin{table}[h]%The best place to locate the table environment is directly after its first reference in text
\caption{\label{tab:table1}%
A table that fits into a single column of a...
}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{ l c }
\textrm{Material}&
\textrm{Bond Length}\\
\colrule
2D Aluminum & \(\thicksim\)2.54 \text{\AA}\\
Cycloaluminum helides & 2.643 \text{\AA}, 2.587 \text{\AA}\\
Aluminum tetramers & 2.773 \text{\AA}, 2.767 \text{\AA}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a working document, not just fragments of code

Comment: I guessing that your problem will be solved by add `centering` after `\begin{table}`, however, I can not test this ... se @ChristianHupfer comment.

Comment: @Zarko: That was my first thought too but `placing the columns nearer to the center of the table` -- I don't think this is `\centering`, but perhaps I am wrong

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, egreg answer show, that I was wrong. I newer use `ruledtabular`, so I was not aware its specifics ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default for `ruledtabular` is to expand it so that it covers all the available column width (which is a wrong thing to do, in my opinion, because tables should be at their natural width).

You can emulate `ruledtabular` and get a table at its natural width:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[h]%The best place to locate the table environment is directly after its first reference in text
\caption{\label{tab:table1}%
A table that fits into a single column of a...
}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{ l c }
\textrm{Material}&
\textrm{Bond Length}\\
\colrule
2D Aluminum & \(\thicksim\)2.54 \text{\AA}\\
Cycloaluminum helides & 2.643 \text{\AA}, 2.587 \text{\AA}\\
Aluminum tetramers & 2.773 \text{\AA}, 2.767 \text{\AA}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[h]%The best place to locate the table environment is directly after its first reference in text
\caption{\label{tab:table2}%
A table that fits into a single column of a...
}
\begin{tabular}{ l @{\qquad} c }
\toprule
\textrm{Material}&
\textrm{Bond Length}\\
\colrule
2D Aluminum & \(\thicksim\)2.54 \text{\AA}\\
Cycloaluminum helides & 2.643 \text{\AA}, 2.587 \text{\AA}\\
Aluminum tetramers & 2.773 \text{\AA}, 2.767 \text{\AA}\\
\botrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use `ruledtabular`, you could add some space (on both sides):

```
\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[h]%The best place to locate the table environment is directly after its first reference in text
\caption{\label{tab:table1}%
A table that fits into a single column of a...
}
\begin{ruledtabular}
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{3em}} l c @{\hspace{3em}}}
\textrm{Material}&
\textrm{Bond Length}\\
\colrule
2D Aluminum & \(\thicksim\)2.54 \text{\AA}\\
Cycloaluminum helides & 2.643 \text{\AA}, 2.587 \text{\AA}\\
Aluminum tetramers & 2.773 \text{\AA}, 2.767 \text{\AA}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]
```

[image]

Comment: hi! how do we extend the lines to full columnwidth?

Comment: @DominicGuana I added a way. You're the judge in which one among the three variants suits you best.

Comment: oh yes! this is what I am looking for. thanks!

Comment: The claim that "tables should be at their natural width" is a bit too broad, in my opinion. I was once the editor of a conference volume -- lots of papers, with lots of tables. The professional in-house book designer I worked with advised to make all but the smallest tables occupy the same width, viz., the width of the text block. (I eventually managed to do so by using `tabular*` environments. This was before David Carlisle created the `tabularx` package!) For sure, the appearance of the conference volume was very good, in no small part because the tables had a good overall uniform "look".

Comment: @Mico I can understand if wide enough tables are set to the column width, in a two column format. Nonetheless, as you said, the book designer added “but the smallest ones”. I have no doubt which format to choose for the present table, among the three shown. In a single column work, tables should possibly be *less* wide than the line.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to thinking about how to narrow down the width of the tabular material -- while, if I understand your objective, keeping a full-column-width outer table -- you should look into improving the spacing between the numbers and "angstrom" symbols. To achieve an improvement, I suggest you load the `siunitx` package and use its `\SI` macro to typeset the number/unit combinations.

To get adequate spacing between the `\colrule` line and the first full data row, consider inserting a "top strut" in the data row, as in done in the following code.

Oh, "indentation" of the data columns may be achieved by defining "dummy" (i.e., unused) columns at the far left and far right of the "real" columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass[reprint, superscriptaddress, showpacs, preprintnumbers, amsmath, amssymb, aps, prb]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}  % "top" strut
\begin{document}

\preprint{APS/123-QED}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table that fits into a single column of a \dots}
\label{tab:table1}
\begin{ruledtabular}
 % First and final "c" columns are dummy (empty) columns
\begin{tabular}{ c l c c }
& Material & Bond Length\\
\colrule
& 2D Aluminum & $\approx$ \SI{2.54}{\angstrom}\Tstrut\\
& Cycloaluminum helides & \SI{2.643}{\angstrom}, \SI{2.587}{\angstrom}\\
& Aluminum tetramers & \SI{2.773}{\angstrom}, \SI{2.767}{\angstrom}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{ruledtabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: alright! I noticed that the 2nd row is too close to the first one, and \Tstrut resolved it. Thanks!